# Python Regex : I would like to find all overlapping and non overlapping pattern matches

Tags: python, regex, list, python-re

I would like to find all overlapping and non overlapping pattern matches

Here is the code:

```
import re

words = [r"\bhello\b",r"\bworld\b",r"\bhello world\b"] 
sentence = "Hola hello world and hello"

for word in words:
    for match in re.finditer(word,sentence):
        print(match.span(),match.group())
```

Gives me the following result (I'm happy about this, but need an efficient way)

```
(5, 10) hello
(21, 26) hello
(11, 16) world
(5, 16) hello world
```

I know this is not very efficient.
Example : Assume I have 20k words and 10k sentences, it would be 200M x 2 calls to re.match which takes a lot of time.

Could you please suggest me an efficient way to solve the problem?

Comment: Do the _words_ contain any non-ordinary character sequences other than `\b` at start and end?

Comment: Hey Armali, I guess no.

Comment: Are the _10k sentences_ in one string, in a list of a myriad strings, or …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different order, but same result and significantly faster likely:

```
import re

substrings=['hello','world','hello world']
joined='|'.join(substrings)
reg=re.compile(rf"\b(?={joined}\b)")

for m in reg.finditer(sentence):
    for e in substrings:
        offset=m.span()[0]
        if sentence[offset:offset+len(e)]==e:
            print((offset,offset+len(e)), e)
```

If you want to make sure that you do not match `hello worldLY` (ie, just the prefix of the substring) you can do:

```
substrings=['hello','world','hello world']
joined='|'.join(substrings)
reg=re.compile(rf"\b(?={joined}\b)")
indvidual=list(map(re.compile, [rf'\b({e})\b' for e in substrings]))
for m in reg.finditer(sentence):
    for i,e in enumerate(indvidual):
        offset=m.span()[0]
        if m2:=e.match(sentence[offset:]):
            print((offset,offset+m2.span()[1]), substrings[i])
```

Either prints:

```
(5, 10) hello
(5, 16) hello world
(11, 16) world
(21, 26) hello
```

Comment: Thanks dawg for the answer, can I get (5, 9) for hello, (5, 15) for hello world and so on as I don't want 10, 16 ? 
PS : I didn’t  want to do print((offset,offset+len(e)-1), e)

Comment: This is the same that you have. Now you want it different? That is one character short...

Comment: Cool, I just fixed it. Thanks a lot, I just did the performance test.

Comment: If you still need faster, have a look at [another data structure](http://kmike.ru/python-data-structures/); specifically a [TRIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie)

Comment: Perfect, it's faster than 2 for loops. Plus you compile it in advance, so it's separate. 
Thanks for the links, will check them in detail
PS : I was not able to use re.I to ignore case sensitive matching, any reason why ?